# WPF Background threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have WPF project, which is basically just a chart. What I what to achieve is update my chart points in background thread, but then I am creating a new thread it crashes.

```
public void UpdateChart()
{
 ... 
}

Thread newThread = new Thread(UpdateChart());
newThread.Start();
```

Exception:

> *Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.*

Comment: I you simply google that error message, you'll get quite a few question and answers, some of them here in SO. I'll suggest first reading about the [WPF Threading Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing well known cross threading access issue. Object of one thread cannot access object of another thread as object pointers are not valid in cross thread context. You can have multiple solutions for it.

- You can create a delegate method which you will be able to call. Google on this and it will yield many results
- Another option is to use thread status events such as completion/progress etc. the Background worker component allows progress reporting. You can use it to update the chart.
- Another method is to use this.invoke(delegate,params[]) system. It will allow you to invoke the method in a different thread without crashing your application.

You will get a lot of material with a simple google search on cross thread gui update in c#. Let me know if you need more information on this.